# java FileNotFoundException for valid URL using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, rest, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on an android application where I'd like to "PUT" some string value to a server. When I manually enter some value to PUT (i.e., content = "data=TEST"), I can see (via Chrome's Advanced REST Client) that the value "TEST" is successfully put.

My issue is that Whenever I try to put a string that I'm getting from another class, I get a huge error block in LogCat that begins with:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myserverthatusuallyworks.com/etc/etcetc/
```

What I don't understand is why it would work when i set the request parameters manually, and not when I use the variable name of the string that the method receives (via my other class).

So, in ClassA.class, once the string that I want to send is set, I do something like this:

```
MyClass Myclass = new MyClass();
Myclass.mymethod(stringtosend);
```

Then, in MyClass.class, My method is set up as:

```
public static mymethod(String mystring) {
 //all the HttpURLConnection stuff here 
}
```

Within mymethod(); where I previously had String content = "data=TEST", I changed it to
    String content = "data="+mystring;

Now, the request wont work and LogCat throws a fit. What's interesting is that I can see via LogCat that the string I really want to send is DEFINITELY defined and prints to the log before I even initialize mymethod();

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure the String to Send is properly encoded to avoid mishaps..

Comment: also is the filepath correct? `com/etc/etcetc` or is it missing a slash `/`?

Comment: @gtgaxiola The file path should be correct, since it is working when I manually set the value. I just set the character encoding to "UTF-8", which works when i set some string like this: String tester = "This is a test", then I encode tester and include it with "data="+testerencoded. I can also see by the log that the string I want is definitely in the class, but for some reason it wont encode at all. I have no idea what the issue is. Its a string of various characters (letters, numbers, and "-" which should be fine), but it's pretty long. IS it possible its too long to be included?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I figured out my issue, its a 500 server error because the string is apparently too long. I figured it out by saving the string to a file from logcat, and manually entering it in my Chrome REST client application. While it's a little off topic, do you know if thats something that can just be set on the server side? By that I mean, can I change the server's web services somehow so that it is willing to accept longer strings? Thanks again for your help

Comment: It may be a PUT limit